# What is the maximum number of files a file system can contain?

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory, ext4

Given the current structure of a directory entry on a ext4 file system on Ubuntu, what is the maximum number of files a file system can contain?

What is the general method of calculating the maximum number of files a file system can contain?

Answer (score 51):

Ext4 has a theoretical limit of 4 billion files, which is restricted by the size of inode number it uses to identify each file (ext4 uses 32-bit inode numbers). However, as John says, ext4 allocates inode tables statically, so the actual limit is set when the filesystem is created.

The df command shows you a count of free inodes on your filesystem:

```
$ df -i

Filesystem        iused     ifree  %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s3   55253386  66810480    45%   /
/dev/disk1s3   55258045  66805821    45%   /Volumes/Clone
```

Ext4 also supports an unlimited number of sub-directories per directory, though it may default to a limit of 64,000. This is configurable -- see the [ext4 article at Kernel Newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4).

For more information, see [The new ext4 filesystem: current status and future plans](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7114603/Ext4-File-System) from the 2007 Linux Symposium.

Comment: This limit of 4 billion shouldn apply nowadays anymore. I have a ext4 filesystem with 4394582016 inodes. So probably ext4 uses 64bit counter for inodes today.

Answer (score 11):

There isn't one, per se; it depends. When you create an ext4 file system, you decide the size of the *inode table*, which in turn governs the total number of directories or files the file system can hold at once.

Comment: you can run `tune2fs -l /path/to/device` and look for the Inode count value to find what the limit is for a given filesystem

Comment: Can we increase the Inode count? As far as I know, inodes are stored as a linked list, so it's just like adding more nodes to the linked list. I guess, the question boils down to what can be the maximum length of a linked list?

Comment: In ext4 the inode table is statically allocated when the filesystem is created. The only way to increase it is to recreate the filesystem. The -N or -i options are used to set the number of inodes created.

Comment: It is also worth noting that directories are files and must be counted as such.

Comment: As are symlinks.  I'm not sure if devices, FIFOs, and sockets count or not.

Comment: @ephemient Yes they do; any entry in the filesystem counts as an inode.

Comment: @Geoff Reedy What if it's a VM? I try to determine this on a Linode box, it has `ext4`. `tune2fs` command says `Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.` probably because of the virtualization.

Comment: `# mkfs.ext4 -N 10000000000 /tmp/big.img` ⇒ *too many inodes (10000000000), specify < 2^32 inodes*

Answer (score 6):

Not Ubuntu, but on Redhat Linux basic commands such as find fail with a 'Too many arguments error' when run against a directory containing 3 million files.  ls runs successfully if no parameters are included, but fails with the same error as soon as filter parameters are added.

Assuming reliability of such basic commands is a mandatory requirement I'd suggest that 3 million files is too many.

Comment: That's not a filesystem restriction though.

Comment: Good point! The FS may support it but the tools will have more and more difficulty to deal with it.